# Why does filter chained with push behave like this?

Tags: javascript

Here's what I did in Chrome's JavaScript console:

```
> var arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4];

> var foo = 3;

> arr.filter(function(value) { return value !== foo });
< [1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4]

> arr.filter(function(value) { return value !== foo }).push(foo);
< 8

> arr.filter(function(value) { return value !== foo }).push(3);
< 8
```

Where did this `8` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) documentation

> **Returns**
>   The new `length` property of the object upon which the method was called.

In your case, `filter` returns an array with 7 elements. After you push another element onto it, the array has 8 elements, and that's what `push` returns.

Answer (score 2):

From [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), `Array.prototype.push` returns:

> The new length property of the object upon which the method was called.

The Chrome console is showing the last value from the previous statement, which is the return from `push`.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.push()` returns the length of the new array, as you can see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

If you want to get a new array from your operation, you should use `Array.prototype.concat()`. But then you would need to call it like: `

```
arr.filter(function(value) { return value !== foo }).concat([foo]);
```

Another way is to use ES6 as:

```
[ ...arr, foo ]
```

It will spread each element of the array. You can take a further look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: Also for a single value, you can call `concat` without wrapping it in an array